# New design cache issues in chat

Tags: discussion, design, chat

After a few days with the new design, some other users and I still experienced that the icons when clicking persons in the chat room experienced seeing the old icons.

I snagged the followed image:

[image]

As can be seen, Hosch250 has gotten the new icons, whilst I still had the old icons. And this is after doing a complete restart of Chrome. Included in the image is the hint to delete your cache, which I did. This fixed the issue in my browser.

(This question is mostly for noting that this has been or is an issue, and that **maybe the cache timeout for these images are a little high**. This also gives the very useful hint of go hunting for the image cache of your browser to remove this issue.)